# synchronise folders according to datetime

Tags: python

I am very new to python and trying to work on this script which recieves data from  multiple ftp sites and download yesterday data  according to date directory to my local folder. but if  the receives fails on any day it would not update that day records and would go to the next day. I want to sync the files   that even if it is  missed on particular it should complete sync teh new files to local folder I have tried looking at rsync but need your help to process it on the script.this is my script.

```
MAX_CHILDREN = 16
    ftp_site_prog = "/usr/local/bin/ftp_site.py"

    class SpawnQ:
        def __init__(self, max_pids):
            self.max_pids = max_pids 
            self.queue = []
            tmp = re.split("/", ftp_site_prog)
            self.my_name = tmp[-1]


        def addQ(self, site_id):
            self.queue.append(site_id)
            return

        def runQ(self):
            while (len(self.queue) != 0):
                # Check how many sessions are running
                cmd = """ps -ef | grep "%s" | grep -v grep""" % self.my_name
                num_pids = 0
                for line in os.popen(cmd).readlines():
                    num_pids = num_pids + 1

                if (num_pids < self.max_pids):
                    site_id = self.queue.pop()
                    # print site_id
                    # print "Forking........"
                    fpid = os.fork()
                    if fpid:
                        # print "Created child: ", fpid
                        os.waitpid(fpid, os.WNOHANG)
                    else:
                        # print "This is the Child"

                        # Exec the ftp_site
                        arg_string = "%s" % site_id
                        args = [arg_string]


           os.execvp(ftp_site_prog, (ftp_site_prog,) + tuple(args))
    how to  call rsync on my py script.//os.system("rsync -ftp_site_prog, (ftp_site_prog,)+ tuple(args))
        sys.exit(0)
                else:
                    # print "Waiting for a spare process...."
                    time.sleep(10)
            return

    # Get a list of the sites
    db_obj = nprint.celDb()
    site_list = db_obj.get_all_site_ids()

    myQ = SpawnQ(MAX_CHILDREN)

    for site_id in site_list:
        myQ.addQ(site_id)

    myQ.runQ()

    # Wait until we only have the parent left
    # Check how many sessions are running
    tmp = re.split("/",ftp_site_prog)
    ftp_name = tmp[-1]
    cmd = """ps -ef | grep "%s" | grep -v grep""" % ftp_name

    num_pids = MAX_CHILDREN
    while (num_pids > 0):
        num_pids = 0
        for line in os.popen(cmd).readlines():
            num_pids = num_pids + 1

        time.sleep(60)

    today = datetime.date.today()
    daydelta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    yesterday = today - daydelta
```

Answer (score 0):

Much of this can be accomplished with the [ftplib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib) for the retrieval of files from standard FTP servers. If you are dealing with SFTP servers you can use the [paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.13/api/sftp.html#module-paramiko.sftp) library.

Comment: but my problem is sync the data on both the folders should be same.

Comment: Ok, so what ideas do you have about how to do that?

Comment: You can't use rsync.. It's a completely different protocol.